# Ant build successfull, cant display servlet

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, ant

I'm trying to work through:

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html#server-setup

installed ant, downloaded appengine sdk, ran cmd as administrator and put in:

```
ant -Dsdk.dir=C:\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0 -Dserver.host=10.0.19.185
```

at example dir.

I got build success and still cant connect to the site:

```
http://10.0.19.185:8080/home
```

as stated in tutorial.

Where have I failed?

Comment: Did you try 'localhost:8080'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to type the runserver command, 
try 
ant -Dsdk.dir=C:\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0 **runserver** -Dserver.host=10.0.19.185